# PHP Ad Manager (free)

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm working with a PHP website that uses a custom CMS based on a MSSQL database.

I'm desperately looking for a solution to install an Ad Manager, and I don't have much time so I would like to know what do you think is the best to do.
What I need to show for the client is a panel with the statistics about the ads (CTR, visits, geolocation).

Here the options I'm thinking of:

- Setup a Google Doubleclick account and then create a PHP panel that communicates with it through the API
- Use a free PHP Ad Manager. The only free one I found is [Orbit Open Ad Server](http://orbitopenadserver.com/) but it works with MySQL. I thought of using it with a remote MySQL of mine but the client's server lacks of PDO Sqlite.
- Create it from scratch, but I think it would take too much. I have got 3 weeks to do this, but there's Christmas \ New Year's Eve, so something like 17-18 days overall.

Any advice?

Comment: This is  a software recommendation site so the only things you should actually ask about is your second option. Can you [edit] your question to match the site requirements, and maybe ad some more criteria that the the software has to match (see http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)? One thing is e.g. that it's completely unclear *what ads* the site is going to serve.